# Corona SDK SegmentedControl Widget Styling

Tags: android, ios, coronasdk

I have a Segmented Control implemented in the game that I'm making.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to style the control outside of the default blue and white theme.  Let's say, I want to just change the blue color in the background of the Segmented Control.  Can I go about doing this through theming (please provide an example)?

Or do I have to go about actually writing my own Segmented Control widget that is styled how I want?  I would really rather avoid this if possible, as I trying to very rapidly develop this app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There were some bugs in the widget library that prevented some of the skinning options to work correctly.  These have been fixed in a recent daily build.  Pro and Enterprise subscribers have access to daily builds where Starter and Basic subscribers do not.  When the next public build comes out, Starter and Basic subscribers will get these features.

Basically you will provide an image sheet of 7 frames:  Left cap selected, middle selected, right cap selected, left cap inactive, middle inactive, right cap inactive and a divider. You won't have to do a whole theme for this.